# Rails 4.2: Set domain for ALL cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to ensure that ALL COOKIES set by my application (session, normal cookies, whatever) uses the top level domain (ie. ".mydomain.com").

I can see how to do this when setting an individual cookie, but I need to ensure it's set for every cookie.

I'm goin' crazy here. Help a guy out!

Answer (score 0):

To access cookies domain name you can do it this way:

```
cookies.instance_variable_get(:@host)
```

And in your session,

```
session.instance_variable_get(:@env)['HTTP_HOST']
```